# How can I force Coded UI Tests to interact with Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm just getting started with Coded UI Tests in VS 2013 for my company's XAML-based desktop applications. For some reason, my tests do not play back correctly if I do not minimize Visual Studio immediately after starting the test playback. I have tried recording the minimize click on VS, but it is not captured.

Is there any way to force Visual Studio to minimize itself when I start the test run?

Comment: Did you record starting the application? If so, did you start it from VS or from the .exe in the bin folder?  When I test WPF apps I create a shortcut to the .exe file and record double-clicking that shortcut as the first step in my test. May not work for production tests, though; haven't tried.

Comment: Agree with @jpg0002, the best way to overcome such issues is to create shortcut of your application on desktop and launch application from there.

Comment: I'm already starting the recording by double-clicking the shortcut to the application. That part works fine. However, when I play the test back, visual studio is still running maximized in the background with seems to cause issues with the interactivity of the running application on playback. I would like for the playback to minimize visual studio as the first step of its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch()` instead of letting your test double-click the shortcut. This will launch the application from the test and shouldn't give any issues when starting the application with VS maximized.